# If all goes well, the examination scheduled for next month (is all set to be/will be) completely free from annoying power cuts

Tags: exam-questions

> If all goes well, the examination scheduled for next month is all set to be completely free from annoying power cuts and disruptions.

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise which says it is error free but he isn't it better to use *will be* in place of *is all set to be* ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what level of English you're using. I would use this as a sentence in speaking, but I would probably use "should be" in an email or text, as it's better English.

The colloquial phrase "All set to be" here implies that it is very likely that the event will occur without power cuts and disruptions, but is not certain. As it's colloquial, "should be" more accurately conveys the slight uncertainty, and is more formal.